# System.threading.timer in a loop giving unexpected results

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, timer

I have a loop that creates timers. I have 2 problems with it.

The first problem is how to run a command as a "fire and forget" so i can call it and it will execute on its own in another thread and it will post back to an API on its own. This is the case if the refresh property is set to 0.

The second is that the parameter in the loop (check.key) is replaced on the next iteration of the loop. When the delegate fires the method, it is passed the replaced value, not the original assigned!!!

In the example below, the values are assigned correctly, but when the delegate fires, it always fires with the parameter "3".

The Dictionary _mydict is filled with data from a remote API.

The classtocall and methodtocall wont always be the same. They can be called more than once - as the key supplied gives access to more parameters in the Test class. The refresh property in the Test class defines the timer time.

I hope this makes sense!

The code (quick mockup as my real code is large):

```
public class Test
{
    public string ClassToCall;
    public string MethodToCall;
    public string UniqueKey;
    public long Refresh;
    // more but removed for sample

    public Test(string MyClass, string MyMethod, string Key)
    {
        this.ClassToCall = MyClass;
        this.MethodToCall = MyMethod;
        this.UniqueKey = Key;
    }
}

class runme
{
    public static void runmefirst(string Key)
    {// Does some processing based on Key
    }

    public static void runmesecond(string Key)
    { // Does some processing based on Key
    }

    public static void runmelast(string Key)
    { // Does some processing based on Key
    }
}

class myclass
{   
    private static Timer[] timers;

    static void Main()
    {

        Dictionary<string, Test> _mydict = new Dictionary<string, Test>();

        _mydict.Add("1", new Test("runme", "runmefirst", "1"));
        _mydict.Add("2", new Test("runme", "runmesecond", "2"));
        _mydict.Add("3", new Test("runme", "runmelast", "3"));

        int i = 0;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,Test> check in _mydict)
        {

            Type t = Type.GetType(check.Value.ClassToCall);
            if (t != null)
            {
                MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod(check.Value.MethodToCall);
                if (mi != null)
                {
                    if (check.Value.Refresh == 0)
                    {
                        mi.Invoke(null, new string[] { check.Key }); // << problem 1: need this fire and forget!
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myclass.timers[i] = new Timer(
                            delegate { mi.Invoke(null, new string[] { check.Key }); }, // << problem 2: when called, check.Key is always last value in loop
                            null,
                            i * 1000,
                            check.Value.Refresh * 5000
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
            i+=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Not got time to type up a full response to this, but you should check out `System.Threading.Tasks` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx), beginning with `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { /* your fire and forget code here */ });` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For the timers part:*

You haven't shown which kind of `Timer` you're using (there are three). If you're using `System.Threading.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer` then I'd expect it to already be executing on the thread pool...

---

*For the wrong value part:*

You're using a loop:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,Test> check in _mydict)
```

and then you're capturing `check` in an anonymous method:

```
delegate { mi.Invoke(null, new string[] { check.Key }); },
```

That's capturing the *variable* `check`, and the value of `check` changes on each iteration. You will always see the last value. This one's easy to fix though:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,Test> check in _mydict)
{
    var copy = check;

    ...

    // Then later...
        delegate { mi.Invoke(null, new string[] { copy.Key }); },
}
```

This time you'll be capturing a "new" local variable on each iteration, and that local variable's value won't change.

Note that the behaviour will change in C# 5 to allow your previous code to work here.

On the other hand, you could just use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to create a delegate directly from the `MethodInfo` and pass that in...

Answer (score 0):

start a new thread

```
System.Threading.Thread mythread = 
new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(MyFunction));
mythread .Start();
```

the function called

```
private void MyFunction()
{
   if (InvokeRequired) 
   {
       this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(MyFunction));
       return;
   }
   //DO YOUR STUFF
}
```